# Adding cert to truststore after upload using SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack, inotify

I have a need to upload a PEM certificate from a SALT minion to the master. I've got the upload working, but I need to figure out how to make the master automatically import the cert into a Java trust store. I know the keytool command to use.

I've found this comment on a SaltStack GitHub issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/42330#issuecomment-315796095

But I'm such a SALT noob that there isn't nearly enough information here to help me figure out how to do the inotify and reactor parts. Saltstack (like OpenStack) is documented for people that have already read and assimilated 98% of the documentation -- even the tutorials assume way too much.

Can anyone point me to some resources on these sub-systems that can help me figure out how to automate the trust store import after the upload completes?